# Passing data to api resource in request doesn't work in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Here's my controller method:

```
public function getQrEntryCardsOfBranch(GetQrEntryCardsRequest $request)
    {
        $request->branch = $request->user()->branch();
        $qrEntryCards = $this->qrEntryCardService->getQrEntryCardsOfBranch($request->branch->id);
        return $this->apiResponse(Result::Success, __('messages.pacs.qrEntryCardsFetched'), QrEntryCardResource::collection($qrEntryCards), 200);
    }
```

And here's my api resource class:

```
class QrEntryCardResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $user = $this->user;
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'user' =>$user ? new SummaryUserResource($user) : null,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'createdAt' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format(DateFormats::Ymd),
            'brandId' => $this->brand_id,
            'branchName' => $request->branch->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

I get an error because $request->branch is null.

I expect it to be not null, because I set it in Controller method.

I expect to be able to add data to $request and reach it from my api resource class but it's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

branch seted in controller. This request not passed to resource.

When a resource class is called in Laravel, the $request object passed to the toArray method of this class is created from the current HTTP request.

you can set branch on HTTP request like that

```
 request()->branch = $request->user()->branch();
```